# JDeveloper 11.1.1.6 weblogic startup issue

Tags: jdeveloper, weblogic-10.x

I created an simple skeletal web application. I created only a simple blank JSF page. Right click and run. Then I got the following message in the Log console.

```
The Server Instance cannot be started because the Integrated Weblogic domain was not built successfully.
```

Can anybody suggest me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not provide detailed information.
The best way would be to go to weblogic domain options from start menu and create a new domain.
Then link that domain in jdeveloper and use the same. Delete the integrated domain i.e. base_domain folder.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 ways this problem can be fixed:

1. Try starting and fixing any issues with the Integrated weblogic domain. Till that is not starting successfully, JDeveloper cannot do anything on that. For me one time startup of the current domain outside of the Jdeveloper solved the issue. After that it was working fine from JDeveloper too.
2. Another option is as stated by vijayinani above to create a new domain and link it. But, beware your integrated base_domain is not having anything which you need to preserve if you plan to delete that.